# ADFv2 Azure Restrict Access to the Publish button

Tags: publish, azure-data-factory, azure-rbac

[Update]
Changes to ADF are deployed using the new CI/CD flow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements#the-new-cicd-flow). SO developers don't need to click publish to manually push changes to create a ARM template.

So developers need to have permissions to develop within ADF but don't need to access to the Publish buttons.

To restrict access to the Publish/Publish All buttons, based on this [RBAC page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-roles-permissions#custom-scenarios-and-custom-roles), is to assign the Contributor role but remove the Data Factory Contributor role.

I've done that but the Publish button is still enabled.

[image]

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Hey, can you be little more clear w.r.t your ask here? In case if you dont want to provide the resource publish access, then best would be to grant the user reader access on ADF. What access is expected by the user?

Comment: @Nandan I've updated to question to clarify. So developers need to have permissions to develop within ADF but don't need to access to the Publish buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#editing-repo-settings) I believe

> If you choose to disable the publish button from the studio, the
> publish button will be grayed out in the studio

In ADF, Go to "Manage" -> Git Configuration -> Edit

[image]